# Extracting anomalous intervals from a data frame

Tags: r

I have a large dataset where I am trying to extract intervals (from the column Zone) where the Anom value is >1 for 5+ consecutive cells, and calculate the means of each interval. In the example below I would like to extract the information that Anom intervals include Zones = 5 to 11 and 17 to 26, but ignoring 28 to 29 (as the number of consecutive cells is <5). Any help is much appreciated.

```
 df <-  data.frame("Zone" = 1:30, "Anom" = 1:30)
 df[,2] <- 0
 df[5:11,2] <- 1
 df[17:26,2] <- 1
 df[28:29,2] <- 1
```

df

```
   Zone Anom
1     1    0
2     2    0
3     3    0
4     4    0
5     5    1
6     6    1
7     7    1
8     8    1
9     9    1
10   10    1
11   11    1
12   12    0
13   13    0
14   14    0
15   15    0
16   16    0
17   17    1
18   18    1
19   19    1
20   20    1
21   21    1
22   22    1
23   23    1
24   24    1
25   25    1
26   26    1
27   27    0
28   28    1
29   29    1
30   30    0
```

The sort of output I would like to generate

```
1 Zone.From Zone.To Anom.Mean
2 5         11      1
3 17        26      1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` and `data.table`'s `rleid` is to create a new group for each change in `Anom`. For each group get `first` and `last` value of `Zone`, `mean` of `Anom`, number of rows in it and `first` value of `Anom`. We can then `filter` and keep only those groups where we have greater than equal to 5 rows and `Anom` is greater than 0.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = data.table::rleid(Anom)) %>%
  summarise(Zone.From  = first(Zone), 
            Zone.To = last(Zone), 
            mean_anom = mean(Anom), 
            N = n(), 
            Anom = first(Anom)) %>%
  filter(Anom > 0 & N >= 5) %>%
  select(-c(grp, N, Anom))

#  Zone.From Zone.To mean_anom
#      <int>   <int>     <dbl>
#1         5      11         1
#2        17      26         1
```